# phpMyAdmin: 403 Error when performing operations on database

Tags: phpmyadmin

The setup: I'm using phpMyAdmin on an AWS Amazon Linux AMI server, with Apache 2.4.27 and PHP 5.6.35. As of about two weeks ago, we've been unable to perform certain actions on the databases. We can reach them just fine and browse tables with no problem; but when trying to perform some actions on these tables, such as sorting columns, we get 403 errors.

Here is my phpMyAdmin.conf file (somewhat edited to hide our IP addresses):

```
    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.95
       Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.43
       Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.9
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.95
       Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.43
       Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.9
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

All my Googling has suggested that in some cases, mod_security might be the problem, but I don't have mod_security installed on this server.

I'm at my wits' end. Can anyone offer any guidance?

**Edited to add:** Neither my error log nor my access log show anything related to this.

Comment: It looks like mod_security was the problem in my case.  Thanks for giving me a lead on this.  I was pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be due to a plugin on a WordPress installation on the same server. I deactivated the plugin, and now my phpMyAdmin installation works fine. Obviously I need to fix my server.

Comment: Yes, Richard. I had same problem, and I have fixed it by your tip. In my server, phpmyadmin folder is in wordpress folder, when I turned off a plugin(=Wordfence Security) phpmyadmin 403 error is exited. I shoud fix my server for more securities of cause. Thanks.

Comment: Same here, disabling Wordfence fixes the issue